# Exporting dataframes within a dict to separate csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary with a year for each key and a dataframe for each value. I need to export these dataframes as CSV files with the key (being the year) as the file name. I've tried running a for loop changing the variable name but doesn't seem to work.
Could someone please outline another method of doing this. Thanks

Comment: Hi user1611612, welcome to SO. Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/hepl/mcve)?

Comment: Your question is very vague, can you provide some more context / the code you've already tried? Even if it didn't work for you it still helps us to figure out whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that different than Charles answer but as [mcve](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and we can even pass integers as year instead of strings.

```py
import pandas as pd
import os

fldr = 'dataframes'
os.makedirs(fldr, exist_ok=True)
diz = {key:pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame().head(10) 
       for key in range(2000,2020)}

for key, value in diz.items():
    value.to_csv(f"{fldr}/{key}.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: The str.format() call in my solution converts integers to strings, so no problem there.

Comment: I didn't say there is any problem with your solution and I upvoted it. I just wanted to provide a full mcve as user1611612 is new here.

Answer (score 1):

As you can easily iterate over keys of a python dictionary, you could do the following :

```py
import pandas as pd

df_dic = {'2017': df1, '2018': df2, '2019': df3}

for key in df_dic:
    df_dic[key].to_csv('{}.csv'.format(key), index=False)
```

This would also work if your keys are integers, as the `.format()` call converts integers to strings.

Notice `index=False`, which allows to avoid storing the dataframes index in the csv.

If you need that index, set `index` to `True`. (It is by default.)